# server doesn't seem to see the content of html form

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

My user registration page has this form:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Ainm">
    <input type="text" name="Password">
    <input type="text" name="Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the corresponding server file has:

```
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//add new user - required fields = username, password, email
app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
    Users.findOne({ Ainm: req.body.Ainm })
      .then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
          return res.status(400).send(req.body.Ainm + " Name already in use.");
        } else {
          Users
            .create({
              Ainm: req.body.Ainm,
              Password:req.body.Password,
              Email: req.body.Email
            })
            .then(function (user) { res.status(201).json(user) })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error(error);
              res.status(500).send("Error: " + error);
            })
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Error: " + error);
      });
  });
```

But when I try to input some test data, I see

```
Undefined Name already in use.
```

Why might the value of Ainm be undefined?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve]. We can't see how you are attaching your body parsing middleware… *are* you attaching any body parsing middleware?

Comment: I might not have "attached" the body-parser. Edited the code above and will google attaching body parser. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

This is your problem.

The form data is not encoded as JSON. It will use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

[You need to use `bodyParser.urlencoded()`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't have bodyparser middleware in your code (having both urlencoded and json to making API generic in future)

if you are using express below 4.16, install body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

else current version (4.16 and above) of express comes with inbuilt bodyParser

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: The `json` body parser will not parse the URL-encoded data that the form submission will contain.